# Set order to array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I need to find a simplest way for setting order to array of objects.
For example, there is an array:

```
var array = [
    {id: 1, name: "Matt"},
    {id: 2, name: "Jack"},
    {id: 3, name: "Morgan"},
    {id: 4, name: "Bruce"}
];
```

and I have provided

```
var order = [1,4,2,3];
```

which refers to object `id` property of `array` items.

Now I need to reorder array so it should be like:

```
var array = [
    {id: 1, name: "Matt"},
    {id: 4, name: "Bruce"},
    {id: 2, name: "Jack"},
    {id: 3, name: "Morgan"}
]
```

Comment: So you have a order, which should be achieved and therefore you want to reorder your array?

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do, You want order arrayobject for Id?

Comment: @Pranav C Balan solved this problem, and he understood, please check. Also @Nenad Vracar has good way for solving this. My `var order` has order of ids from `array` objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use **[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** method for sorting and inside custom sort function use **[`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOF)** method to get index.

```js
var array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Matt"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Jack"
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Morgan"
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Bruce"
}];

var order = [1, 4, 2, 3];


array.sort(function(a, b) {
  // sort based on the index in order array
  return order.indexOf(a.id) - order.indexOf(b.id);
})

console.log(array);
```

Comment: What should the function passed return? A number value? A boolean value?

Comment: @user6245072 :  a number , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `reduce()` on `[1,4,2,3]` array to return object where keys will be elements and values will be index of each element and then sort by that object.

```js
var array = [
  {id: 1, name: "Matt"},
  {id: 2, name: "Jack"},
  {id: 3, name: "Morgan"},
  {id: 4, name: "Bruce"}
];

var s =  [1,4,2,3].reduce((r, e, i) => {return r[e] = i, r}, {});
var result = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return s[a.id] - s[b.id];
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess anything that involves sort can not be more efficient than an O(2n) solution. So i would like to do this job with two reduces as follows;

```js
var arr = [{id: 1, name: "Matt"}, {id: 2, name: "Jack"}, {id: 3, name: "Morgan"}, {id: 4, name: "Bruce"}],
  order = [1,4,2,3],
    lut = order.reduce((t,e,i) => (t[e] = i,t),{}),
 result = arr.reduce((res,obj) => (res[lut[obj.id]] = obj, res) ,[]);
 console.log(result);
```